# Hide control on LostFocus

Tags: wpf

When ever the focus lost from both txtBoxes (the "*value*" fields) i want to hide them.
I have commented the option i tried, since it cause the "*GrdAmountInDollars*" not to be shown at all.
any ideas?
thx in advance

My Xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"

    Title="MainWindow" Height="150" Width="525" FlowDirection="LeftToRight">

<Window.Resources>

    <Style x:Key="MyTemplate" TargetType="{x:Type ContentControl}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ContentControl}">
                    <Grid VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0,4,0,0" Height="60">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="2"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="2"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="2"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="4"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="4"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="2"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="2"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="2"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                        <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Focusable="False" Text="From amt" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="0"/>
                        <TextBox x:Name="tbxMinQtyRange" Grid.Column="2" MaxLength="12"
                                           Text="{Binding MinQtyRange, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                                           HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"  Width="54" Padding="0" Margin="0" Height="20" VerticalAlignment="Center" Grid.ColumnSpan="1" />

                        <TextBlock Grid.Column="4" Focusable="False" Text="To amt" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="0" />
                        <TextBox x:Name="tbxMaxQtyRange" Grid.Column="6" MaxLength="12"
                                         Text="{Binding MaxQtyRange, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus}"
                                         HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"  Width="54" Padding="0" Margin="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="1" Height="20" VerticalAlignment="Center" />



                        <CheckBox x:Name="chkAmountInValue" FlowDirection="LeftToRight" Grid.Column="8" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="1" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>
                        <TextBlock x:Name="textBlock" Grid.Column="10" Focusable="False" Text="value" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="0" />

                        <Grid x:Name="GrdAmountInDollars" Grid.ColumnSpan="7" Grid.Column="10" Visibility="Collapsed">
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="2"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="2"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="2"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                            <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Focusable="False" Text="value" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="0"/>
                            <TextBox x:Name="TbxMinValRange" Text="{Binding MinValRange, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Grid.Column="2" Width="54"
                     Margin="0" Height="20" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>

                            <TextBlock Grid.Column="4" Focusable="False" Text="to" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="0" />
                            <TextBox x:Name="TbxMaxValRange" Text="{Binding MaxValRange, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus}" Width="54"
                     Margin="0" Height="20" Grid.Column="6"/>



                        </Grid>

                    </Grid>

                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger SourceName="chkAmountInValue" Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
                            <Setter TargetName="textBlock" Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
                            <Setter TargetName="GrdAmountInDollars" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                            <Setter TargetName="TbxMinValRange" Property="FocusManager.FocusedElement"
                                             Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"/>
                        </Trigger>

                        <!--<MultiTrigger>
                            <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                <Condition SourceName="TbxMinValRange" Property="IsFocused" Value="False"/>
                                <Condition SourceName="TbxMaxValRange" Property="IsFocused" Value="False"/>
                            </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                            <MultiTrigger.Setters>
                                <Setter TargetName="chkAmountInValue"  Property="IsChecked" Value="False"/>
                            </MultiTrigger.Setters>
                        </MultiTrigger>-->
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>

                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>

</Window.Resources>

<ContentControl Style="{StaticResource MyTemplate}" IsTabStop="False"/>
</Window>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace the commented code with below code.
Your code doesn't work because MultiTriggers works like an **AND** operation. ie if both textboxes' `IsFocused` is set to false, then only the checkbox is unchecked.

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=TbxMinValRange, Path=IsFocused}" Value="False">
<Setter TargetName="chkAmountInValue"  Property="IsChecked" Value="False"/>
</DataTrigger>

<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=TbxMaxValRange, Path=IsFocused }" Value="False">
<Setter TargetName="chkAmountInValue"  Property="IsChecked" Value="False"/>
</DataTrigger>
```

Comment: thank you, answering. I want it to be with **"and"**. except that, your suggested answer doesn't cause the ui to change behaviour.

Comment: There may be some other logic too behind the checkbox status as explained in the code. Without knowing that, I cant help you fix it.

Comment: at the moment, there's no code behind. if such needed, plz advice me, what sort of code I should add

Comment: So this is your entire code? Did you fix the issue?

Comment: Yes this all it is. And no, still working on solution

Comment: I have tried it now. Your question would cause ambiguity and the requirement is not clear either. When you check the checkbox you want to display the textboxes and on lost focus uncheck the checkbox. This would cause confusion to the user though. And it's not possible to have focus on both text boxes at the same time. So what you're trying to achieve is something impossible. You're trying to create something like an infinite loop between the checkbox and those 2 textboxes. I am afraid, nobody could fix your issue. Please recheck your requirement. @eran:

Comment: The only solution i can think is involving RoutedEvent (onLOstFocus) which is not an mvvm solution. I will mark it solved, though its not the way I intended it  to be. I will pop a "values panel" with ok button). thank you very much for the help.